# Error In Notification Parse

Tags: android

Please Help

This Error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/parse/ParseFacebookUtils$1.class

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.eaglegroup.hmusic"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.12.0.jar')
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
}
```

And This ScreenShot

http://upload7.ir/u/preview/s1/GMUCEmdE.png

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem that happened to you. I solved it by doing the following steps.
In your project's **app/libs** folder, remove the below files and folder.

1. **ParseFacebookUtilsV3-1.10.4-javadoc** (*It's a folder*)
2. **ParseFacebookUtilsV3-1.10.4.jar** (*An Executable jar file*)
3. **ParseFacebookUtilsV3-1.10.4.jar.properties** (*A Properties file*)

By doing this, I solved mine. I think this should help.